# Is it faster to make a variable for the length of a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, reverse

I am implementing a `reverse(s)` function in Python 2.7 and I made a code like this:

```
# iterative version 1
def reverse(s):
    r = ""
    for c in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
        r += s[c];
    return r

print reverse("Be sure to drink your Ovaltine")
```

But for each iteration, it gets the length of the string even though it's been deducted.

I made another version that

```
# iterative version 2
def reverse(s):
    r = ""
    l = len(s)-1
    for c in range(l, -1, -1):
        r += s[c];
    return r

print reverse("Be sure to drink your Ovaltine")
```

This version remembers the length of the string and doesn't ask for it every iteration, is this faster for longer strings (like a string that has the length of 1024) than the first version or does it have no effect at all?

Comment: Measure it and see if it makes a significant difference.

Comment: "But for each iteration, it gets the length of the string even though it's been deducted." - why do you think that ?

Comment: @juanchopanza Do you mean measure the strings?

Comment: No, measure the time the two programs take.

Comment: Both versions call the `len` function just once - there's no difference. What you probably have in mind is [LICM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion), which is generally a good idea, but doesn't apply here.

Comment: +1 to @thg435 ! and not only that, in both versions `range` is being calculated only once!

Comment: I am pretty sure the fastest python method is likely to be using stringvariable[::-1] -- though not a direct answer to your specific question.

Comment: I watched a video lecture on a course where the professor said that the for-loop in C repeatedly uses the `strlen()` of a string and said that it's wise to make a variable to avoid that redundancy so I thought it also applies to Python's for-loop and `range()` function.

Comment: an indexing expression (in this case just `s[::-1]`) would be faster than either one.

Comment: @aestrivex that would be faster but I am implementing an iterative version of the `reverse(s)` function.

Comment: For a large enough string it will spend most of its time in  doing the string concat of  `r += s[c]`. Because each time you add one char it's a new string object.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [12]: %timeit reverse("Be sure to drink your Ovaltine")
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.53 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit reverse1("Be sure to drink your Ovaltine")
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.55 µs per loop
```

`reverse` is your first method, `reverse1` is the second.

As you can see from timing there is very little difference in the performance.

You can use `Ipython`  to time your code with the above syntax, just def your functions and use `%timeit` and then your function and whatever parameters .

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
for c in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
```

`len(s)` is evaluated *only once*, and the result (minus one) passed as an argument to `range`. Therefore the two versions are almost identical - if anything, the latter may be (very) slightly slower, as it creates a new name to assign the result of the subtraction.

Comment: As seen in the @Padraic's answer, the latter is indeed, slightly slower